# Error with newly migrated Certified NFT Collection

Tags: web3.js, nft, javascript, metaplex-js, collection

I just migrated my NFT collection to the new Metaplex certified collection standard using their tool at [link](https://collections.metaplex.com/)

Now when I try and run `.nfts().update()` I get the following error

```
Source: Program > TokenMetadataProgram [metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s]

>> Problem: The program [TokenMetadataProgram] at address [metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s] raised an error of code [101] that translates to "Can't use this function on unsized collection".
```

How can I size the collection?  I would like to be able to update our NFTs again ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the great team over at Metaplex actaully fixed this issue.  Turns out it was a bug in the JS SDK.

Loris pushed an update and I verified it now works great!

Make sure to use @metaplex-foundation/js v 0.16.0 or later [NPM listing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@metaplex-foundation/js)

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround i tried,
I create a new NFT collection using the `create` method. passing the `isCollection` and `collectionIsSized` to true.
then i updated my nfts to use this collection.
Now i can update my nfts using the `update` method.

```
const result = await create({
    name: metadata.name,
    symbol: metadata.symbol,
    uri,
    isCollection: true,
    collectionIsSized: true,
  });
```